# What is this error in the Sitecore error logs?

Tags: jss, logging

On a *Sitecore 9.1 Initial Release* site with JSS (Angular JS), we are noticing a large number of these errors in the Sitecore logs:

```
15888 15:09:55 ERROR ERROR [Error]
```

This is the entire error message, and it's not obvious to see what could be causing it. I've had a good look through configuration and decompiling binaries to try and see what might be raising this, but without luck.

Has anyone come across this and knows what this is related to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out after some digging, the error underneath that ERROR ERROR [Error] is

"TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

Dilemma averted, however I'd love to know how that error message was suppressed in favour of ERROR ERROR [Error].

Comment: This was it - as stated above it was an Angular JS error being thrown that was not logging anything besides what we saw.